# how to save pictures larger than 1MB in database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i save my picture as follows:

```
$cn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'xkmpfg3t', 'test');

foreach (glob('*.jpg') as $img) {
    $picName = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, "$img");
    $picData = file_get_contents($img);
    mysqli_query($cn, "INSERT INTO `pictures` (`user_id`,`picture_id`,`picture_name`,`picture`) VALUES ('1','','$picName','$picData')");

   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, "INSERT INTO `pictures` (`user_id`,`picture_id`,`picture_name`,`picture`) VALUES ('1','NULL',?,?)")or die(mysqli_errno($cn));


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sb",$picName,$picData);


    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

and when the picture is under 1mb everyhting works just fine but when the picture is overe a 1mb i see only the name of picture. I have the folowing colomns in my database user_id (int), picture_id(int)PK, picture_name(varchar), picture(mediumblob).
The setting of my.ini file are :

```
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 50M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

the post_max_file and upload_max_filesize are 256M.I don't recive any error or warning everything work i don't know what to do please help.

Comment: You should post your mysql table, what kind of data field are you saving it in, in a Blob?

Comment: not blob it is a mediumblob

Comment: Weird cause that should be more than enough. Are you sure it's going wrong at the mysql side, is this script called from a form? If so, you may also check your php.ini file cause you can also have limitations over there.

Comment: It is not called from a form... i execute the script directly. I've tried everything but nothing is working.

Comment: I personally never store large portions of binary data into a database cause it can make the db slow. Why don't you store the binary in a file instead and store the link to the file in the database? Perhaps it's a memory issue, all this stuff has to go into ram if you store it in the db like that?

Comment: I played with blob data type and i saw that problem i didn't think that it will be so big pain in the ass to solve this problem. I wanna save them in the database because there will be not more than 10 pictures at all and they will be common for all users.

Comment: Even if it's only 1 file, I would still store it on disk. But anyway, can you check where exactly it goes wrong, I mean, is the data actually stored in the database when you login to the db command line? Or is the problem with reading from it?

Comment: If the picture is less than 1mb there is a record but if it is over 1mb only the id pic_id and the name is recorded but the picture data itself is missing

Comment: Can you set your PDO max buffer size, cause that one defaults to 1 MB: PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE. You can either do this in php,ini or at the top of your script. Even though you run the script directly, it still uses php.ini.

Comment: Since you're using `bind_param`, which is correct, you do not need to escape the value. Now you're double escaping it. Remove the unnecessary manual escape call. It's also worth noting that storing large binary values in your database usually leads to a world of hurt, so I'd strongly advise you to store the *path* to the image in the database and keep the image as a regular file on disk.